# How should I adjust the width and height in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

The plot seems like be crowded together.
[image]

How should I widen the plot like that:
[image]

`ggsave()` may adjust them when I save it as a picture, but I'm going to show it in Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about what `pr` is, and what is your color index is about, but I guess that as `prime_genre`.

Instead of `facet_grid`, try `facet_wrap(.~prime_genre, nrow = 1)`

Make sure in `.~` part of `facet_grid`, put the variable that `group` or `color` in your `pr` thing.

Comment: It works! And much better than I expected！Thank you~!